# Различие версий jQuery

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.

Нашел реализацию для тултипов нужную, но `jQuery` там используется 1.2.2 старый, а с новым код не работает. Подскажите что нужно поменять что бы адаптировать под новый `jQuery 1.7.2` например. И верно ли указать паузу в виде

```
$tooltip.delay(1000).hide().fadeIn(this.fadeeffect[1])?
```

Спасибо.

```
var ajaxtooltip={
    fadeeffect: [true, 300], //enable Fade? [true/false, duration_milliseconds]
    useroffset: [10, 10], //additional x and y offset of tooltip from mouse cursor, respectively
    loadingHTML: '',//'<div style="font-style:italic"><img src="../../engine/ajax/tooltips/ajaxload.gif" /></div>',

    positiontip:function($tooltip, e){
        var docwidth=(window.innerWidth)? window.innerWidth-15 : ajaxtooltip.iebody.clientWidth-15
        var docheight=(window.innerHeight)? window.innerHeight-18 : ajaxtooltip.iebody.clientHeight-15
        var twidth=$tooltip.get(0).offsetWidth
        var theight=$tooltip.get(0).offsetHeight
        var tipx=e.pageX+this.useroffset[0]
        var tipy=e.pageY+this.useroffset[1]
        tipx=(e.clientX+twidth>docwidth)? tipx-twidth-(2*this.useroffset[0]) : tipx //account for right edge
        tipy=(e.clientY+theight>docheight)? tipy-theight-(2*this.useroffset[0]) : tipy //account for bottom edge
        $tooltip.css({left: tipx, top: tipy})
    },

    showtip:function($tooltip, e){
        if (this.fadeeffect[0])
            $tooltip.hide().fadeIn(this.fadeeffect[1])
        else
            $tooltip.show()
    },

    hidetip:function($tooltip, e){
        if (this.fadeeffect[0])
            $tooltip.fadeOut(this.fadeeffect[1])
        else
            $tooltip.hide()
    }

}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    ajaxtooltip.iebody=(document.compatMode && document.compatMode!="BackCompat")? document.documentElement : document.body
    var tooltips=[] //array to contain references to all tooltip DIVs on the page
    $('*[@title^="ajax:"]').each(function(index){ //find all links with "title=ajax:" declaration
        this.titleurl=jQuery.trim(this.getAttribute('title').split(':')[1]) //get URL of external file
        this.titleposition=index+' pos' //remember this tooltip DIV's position relative to its peers
        tooltips.push($('<div class="ajaxtooltip"></div>').appendTo('body'))
        var $target=$(this)
        $target.removeAttr('title')
        $target.hover(
            function(e){ //onMouseover element
                var $tooltip=tooltips[parseInt(this.titleposition)]
                if (!$tooltip.get(0).loadsuccess){ //first time fetching Ajax content for this tooltip?
                    $tooltip.html(ajaxtooltip.loadingHTML).show()
                    $tooltip.load(this.titleurl, '', function(){
                        ajaxtooltip.positiontip($tooltip, e)
                        ajaxtooltip.showtip($tooltip, e)
                        $tooltip.get(0).loadsuccess=true
                    })

                }
                else{
                    ajaxtooltip.positiontip($tooltip, e)
                    ajaxtooltip.showtip($tooltip, e)
                }
            },
            function(e){ //onMouseout element
                var $tooltip=tooltips[parseInt(this.titleposition)]
                ajaxtooltip.hidetip($tooltip, e)        
            }
        )
        $target.bind("mousemove", function(e){
            var $tooltip=tooltips[parseInt(this.titleposition)]
            ajaxtooltip.positiontip($tooltip, e)
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Судя по коду, это очень "кривой" тултип, советую поискать получше, благо их [навалом][1].

 [1]: https://www.google.ru/search?q=tooltip+jquery

Comment: тултип можно вообще самому написать. Это ведь всего лишь всплывающая подсказка.

Comment: можно. title="блаблабла", или <div style="display:none;"></div> и отображение блока при наведении, ну а когда данные из базы в эту подсказку должны попадать без размещения изначально на странице с учетом что в ajax я ноль? разве бы я спрашивал если бы сам знал что поправить )